# How to run Vue.js from within iOS/Android app?

Tags: android, ios, vue.js

Currently we have an app contains a webview, in webview the url address is our remote server. Problem is that when start app it will connect to our server to download html/js/css to show content. If network is slow, it will take long time to show a white screen.

For traditional html/css/js, we can just put all the contents in a local folder, then tell webview to load content from that local folder.

But we are using Vue.js. As you may know, even we build Vue.js to /dist folder, you cannot directly use file:// to access them, it must depends on a server.

So my question is: how can we run a small server in iOS/Android app to serve these /dist contents? So that webview can access http://localhost:8080 something to show the content.

Thank you!

Comment: I have exact same requirement. and I am stuck. Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @Nightswatch The only way I think of is to bundle a termux in app and run a nginx server in it. You can google for "termux".

Answer (score 1):

Webview cannot access localhost.  Think about it, webview is running on someone's device, and that device doesn't (and can't ever) know what localhost is. If the http requests in your vue app go out to an actual, live http:// or https:// server, then the vue instantiation will work in a WebView (at least in Android, which is what I know).